# Construct neighbors list based on condition

Tags: r, spatial-analysis

I am trying to build a neighbors list based on regions with contiguous boundaries, conditional on if a neighboring region has a policy implemented.

For example, say I have census tracts in New York State. Each tract is identified as having the policy or not having the policy. If a tract does not have the policy, I want to know how many linkages (if any) it has with counties that do have the policy.

```
library(tigris)
library(tmap)
library(poly2nb)
library(tidyverse)

# Reproducible data
set.seed(1)
tracts <- tracts(state = "NY", county= c("001", "083", "039","95","93")) %>%
  mutate(policy= sample(c('yes', 'no'), 183, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6))) 

# plot it
tm_shape(tracts) +
  tm_fill(col = "policy")+
  tm_borders()
```

[image]

I know I can use the `poly2nb` package to find the number of neighbors, but I don't know how to make this conditional. Is there a way to modify the code below, conditional on the presence of the policy?

```
# Contiguity matrix
col_nbQ = poly2nb(tracts, queen = T)    # Queen-style contiguity
col_nbR = poly2nb(tracts, queen = F)    # Rook-style contiguity
summary(col_nbQ)
```

My desired result is a summary of how counties without the policy are linked to counties with the policy.

Comment: You could build a neighbor matrix with Nth order contingency and then loop through the neighbor list to identity neighbors that meet your criteria. The values in the neighbors list correspond to the row index so, it is easy to subset and query the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the neighbors list, subset the Nth order neighbors and apply a query that is then assigned to a vector. Here is an example, note that I am using the `queen_weights` and `get_neighbors` functions from the rgeoda library. You can easily modify the code to use the poly2nb or spdep libraries.

```
library(sf)
library(rgeoda)
set.seed(42)

d <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
```

Here we add a random policy field to the data and calculate 1st order Queen contingency.

```
d$policy <- sample(c("yes","no"), nrow(d), replace = TRUE)
  nbr <- queen_weights(d)
```

Now, we can set up an iterator, using lapply, to evaluate our condition. The first example is evaluating if there is an adjacent county that has the policy (eg. policy=yes) and the second is return counts of adjacent counties that have the policy. The get_neighbors function returns the neighbor indices for each observation (using the iterator i).

```
d$policy.true <- 
  unlist(lapply(1:nrow(d), function(i) {  
    if(any(d[get_neighbors(nbr, i),]$policy == "yes")) 
    { TRUE } else { FALSE } }))

# plot(d["policy.true"])

plot(st_geometry(d))
plot(st_geometry(d[which(!d$policy.true),]), 
     col="black", add=TRUE)
title("Counties with no adjacent policy implemented")
```

[image: Counties with no adjacent policy implemented]

```
d$policy.cts <- 
  unlist(lapply(1:nrow(d), function(i) {  
    length(which(d[get_neighbors(nbr, i),]$policy == "yes"))}))

plot(d["policy.cts"])
```

[image: policy counts]

Comment: Thank you. Your answer has been very helpful.